# android application Gradle task [:app:assembleDebug] error

Tags: java, android-studio

Am trying to build my first hello world program, and am encountering different error messages, like **Gradle build fail, and so on**. This one below is the Latest and the last of it all, While rebuilding it output:

**Gradle task [:app:assembleDebug] error**

**java.util.Concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.runtimeException: No server to serve Request**

Have tried different solutions, i have downloaded Gradle latest version, set my path to it.
The Editor is Coming up nice but sometimes it fail to show up, but that's not a big deal.
At the moment, i can not successfully build the program have designed or written. Please Someone Help me!.

Below is the Image file which output the Error message am unable to solve at the moment.

[The Link to the Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1GHU.png)

Comment: please just click on "This is my current problem with android studio" it will show the image file.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work that way. Post your information into your question itself as text, not images. Use images to provide clarifying information that can only be shown visually.

Comment: i Think the image says it all, for the question i have. Am not good at using Stackoverflow, the last time i tried, i was down voted.

Comment: You need to give a details of your problem. The image can't explain anything without a context.

Comment: it's not that you are not good at using stackoverflow, it;s that you are lazy. People can't help you from an image if they want to copy and paste your code. Now do what I asked and put your code into the body of your question and perhaps someone will help you. To give you my perspective, I was reluctant to click on your link without more information in case it was a malware link. And as the previous commenter stated, you need to provide some details, some context. Read [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Have found the solution to my problem.